# ListView Goes To Different Activities

Tags: android, listview, onclick

Ok, I'm very new to Android Development and Programming in general. I have a listView with two items in it, when a user clicks it I want each to go to a different Activity. Here's the code I have so far.

```
package com.pais.convert;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class list extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      String[] choose = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_chooser);
      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, choose));

      ListView lv = getListView();
      lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, tempConvert.class);
        intent.putExtra("KEY_SELECTED_INDEX", position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    }
```

So here when it clicks both will go to the tempConvert.class. I want the one that says "Temp" go to tempConvert and when "Dist" is clicked it goes to distConvert.class. How would I accomplish this?

Thanks In Advance For The Help

Answer (score 2):

Inside onListItemClick, make a switch statement with the int position parameter. Then, if it is 0, you go to one class, if it is 1, you go the other one.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    switch(position) {
        case '0' :            
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, tempConvert.class);
            intent.putExtra("KEY_SELECTED_INDEX", position);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case '1' :            
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, distConvert.class);
            intent.putExtra("KEY_SELECTED_INDEX", position);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        intent = new Intent(this, tempConvert.class);
        break;
    case 1:
        intent = new Intent(this, distConvert.class);
        break;
    }
    if (intent != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        // report unknown item selection
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I wanted to add more Activities to be opened all I would have to do is add more Cases yes? Thanks

Comment: That's how I would do it. You might be able to make it a little more robust to changes in your interface by relying on the id instead of the position, but that's a judgment call.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
Intent intent = null;
switch (position) {
case 0:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, tempConvert.class));
    break;
case 1:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, distConvert.class));
    break;
}

}
```